# ActionScript 3 - Flash CS 5 - Input Textbox abnormal behavior?

Tags: flash

The problem I am currently facing is that when I enter text in an Input Text box and then modify a word by inserting character by pressing 'Insert' key on keyboard the immediate character next to the inserted character disappears. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what the insert button does; what it's for. Not Flash's fault. It used to be like that in the older versions of MS Word too. Just make sure you turn it off :)

(Edit) I have found some info on how to disable keyboard buttons in flash, **[this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fac.html)** might just work for you.

Comment: ohh, I check with MS word 2007, and few other word editors before posting, dint knew about behavior in older versions MS word.

Comment: Never thought of this possible solution :-) - Thanks